# Problems rendering a user Defined filter type in a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Using the LexikFilterBundle types I create a subform on my main form so:

```
    ->add('adressData', CollectionAdapterFilterType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => AddressFilterType::class,
        'add_shared' => function (FilterBuilderExecuterInterface $qbe) {
            $qbe->addOnce($qbe->getAlias() . '.adressData', 'a');
        },
        'label' => 'person.address',
    ))
```

My AddressFilterType is so defined:

```
// EyeColorFilterType.php
namespace AppBundle\Filter;


use AppBundle\Entity\AdressData;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;
use AppBundle\Repository\AddressRepository;
use AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository;
use AppBundle\Repository\EyeColourRepository;
use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\FilterOperands;
use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\TextFilterType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type as Filters;


class AddressFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street', TextFilterType::class, [
                'condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_CONTAINS])
            ->add('city', TextFilterType::class, [
                'condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_CONTAINS])
            ->add("country", CountryType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    "class" => "countryselect2",
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'address.choosecountry',
                'label' => "address.country",
                'translation_domain' => "address",
            ]);

    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'address_filter';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => AdressData::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'address'
        ));
    }

    // this allow us to use the "add_shared" option
    public function getParent()
    {
        return Filters\SharedableFilterType::class;
    }
}
```

Now in my twig template which I pass my AddressFilterType into:

```
                        {% embed ":addressdata/forms:filter.html.twig" with{"address":form.adressData} %}{%  endembed %}
```

If I then simply call form_row(addressdata) it works (city, street and country are rendered as defined in the AddressFilterType shown above. But if I try to render the fields myself it fails. Why is this? Says no such methods as getCountry() for example. Totally confused as to how to access these fields when I pass the adressData and adminAdressData component of the main form to an include template.

```
{# @var address \AppBundle\Entity\AdressData #}
{#{{ form_row(address) }}#}
<div class=" row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_row(address.country) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_row(address.city) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" row">
        {{ form_row(address.street) }}
</div>
```

POST EDIT :

The solution was

```
{% embed ":addressdata/forms:filter.html.twig" with{"address":form.adressData[0]} %}{%  endembed %}
```

I don't know why since there should only be one form.

Comment: I don't know `LexikFormFilterBundle`, but it looks like `form.adressData` which you're passing to `filter.html.twig` as `address` variable is instance of `CollectionAdapterFilterType`, and not `AddressFilterType` as you might think.

Comment: I'm using Idea/PHPStorm could you advise me how to debug whats in the twig template please. Just use dump()? The dump() shows two FormViews and expanding the first form passed: FormView {#3827 ▼
  +vars: array:24 [▶]
  +parent: FormView {#2509 ▶}
  +children: array:1 [▼
    0 => FormView {#3836 ▼
      +vars: array:24 [▶]
      +parent: FormView {#3827}
      +children: array:3 [▼
        "street" => FormView {#3840 ▶}
        "city" => FormView {#3843 ▶}
        "country" => FormView {#3845 ▶}
      ]
      -rendered: false
    }
  ]
  -rendered: false
}

Comment: So, thanks to your hint I merely passed in adressData[0] . I dont know why this should be like that but it works now. Thanks you.

Comment: That's because `CollectionAdapterFilterType` handles a **collection** of your `entry_type` which is in your case `AddressFilterType`.